# How to access the nested Embedded Schema fieldsin C# Fragement

Tags: 2011, templating, tom.net, 2011-sp1

I have three Schema A (Content) , B(Embedded), C(Embedded)

Schema A have fields A1(text) and A2(EmbeddedSchema)

Schema B have fields B1(EmbeddedSchema), B2(text) 
And
Schema C have fields C1(text) and C2(text)

Schema B is embedded with field A2 and Schema C is embedded with  field B1.

**How to get the value of  C1 field in C# TBB/Fragment.**

I am doing to get the value  of field A2 (document_order) with below code but unable to get the in field C1

```
if (pubMetadata.Contains("order_sort"))
{    
    foreach (ItemFields docsort in ((EmbeddedSchemaField)pubMetadata["order_sort"]).Values) 
    {
        //Below code line works 
        string docOrder = ((KeywordField)docsort["document_order"])
                              .Value.Description.ToString();

        //Below code line is not working 
        string docSortName = ((KeywordField)docsort["doc_sort"])
                                 .Value.Description.ToString();                   
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you please share your actual schema definitions? It's difficult to map your code to your abstract explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The general pattern is that the value of an EmbeddedSchemaField is an ItemFields collection.

So, something along these lines should work (I didn't test this)

```cs
ItemFields fields = new ItemFields(Component.Content, Component.Schema);
EmbeddedSchemaField embedded1 = (EmbeddedSchemaField)fields["EmbeddedSchemaFieldName"];
ItemFields embeddedFields = embedded1.Value;
EmbeddedSchemaField embedded2 = (EmbeddedSchemaField)embeddedFields["EmbeddedSchemaField2Name"];
ItemFields embeddedFields2 = embedded2.Value;
```

Pay attention to multi-value Embedded Schema fields, and all else failing, use the [DGX extension](http://www.sdltridionworld.com/community/extension_overview/dreamweaver_get_extension.aspx) from [c# Building Blocks](http://nunolinhares.blogspot.com/2011/08/using-dreamweaver-field-notation-in.html).

Comment: Thanks Nuno. Dreamweaver Get Extension meets my requirement.